# Return sorted list in Java

Tags: java, oop, sorting, collections, refactoring

I am coding something like this:

```
List<Bean> beans = service.findBeans();
Collections.sort(beans, new BeanComparator());
return beans;
```

It works perfectly. What I am looking for is a shortcut to do this with just one line:

```
return somelibrary.Collections.sort(service.findBeans(), new BeanComparator());
```

Or:

```
return somelibrary.newList(service.findBeans(), new BeanComparator());
```

Note that it is required a mutable list.

Comment: what is wrong with the original?

Comment: What is the purpose of the library if it's just doing the exact same thing that `Collections.sort` already provides?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. It works. I am looking for a shortcut to do what I want with just one line.

Comment: Your original code looks great.  Why change it? Three lines is better than one in my opinion. Why do people think it's better to jam a bunch of code into one line? Leave it as is and enjoy the readability!

Comment: It is java, the most things need more than one line.

Comment: You'd rather make your project depend on another MB of JARs than write a single function that makes it a one-liner to sort the list? I don't understand your motivation.

Comment: Talk about anti-optimization!

Comment: @Marko The real problem here isn't that one version is longer than the other, or that we'd have to add another dependency. *If* the proposed API was well designed and made sense, I'd be the first that would want it added to the standard API (though there's a long list of really sensible, good functions the collections API is badly missing). The real problem is that an in-place sort **shouldn't** return its input parameter, because that would make for a bad API design. Most people would expect a `sort` that returns a Collection, to return a sorted *copy* of the input parameter.

Comment: @Voo `return new StringBuilder().append("a").append("b").toString();` -- it's convenience that counts.

Comment: @Marko It's always a tradeoff, but do you really think anybody would expect the `append` of StringBuilder to return a new instance? I don't think so, also the usage scenario is completely different compared to sort. For `sort` it's quite likely that the function returns a sorted copy of the input parameter - indeed many APIs offer two different ways to sort something, one in-place one not.

Comment: @Voo I am always in favor of compact code. Many people get confused by `BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(1); x.add(1);` thinking they are changing `x` -- but they get used to it. I curse many times at `void` methods that could just as well returned their argument. It can be a matter of not one line of difference, but 4-5 lines when you can't compose functions directly in a return statement, but have to break up everything, declare vars for partial results, etc.

Comment: @Marko And I'm in favor of code where people don't have to guess what it is doing if it can be avoided. Yes, compact is good, but only if it doesn't lead to confusion. I mean if compact, unreadable (except for the author) code is the goal, there's always perl ;) I'm more the python guy. Setters where we modify one object repeatedly is generally fine, but `sort` doesn't fall into that category. Edit: trutheality said that much more eloquent than I could've :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik There's a difference between composition `f(g(h(a)`, and repeated mutation of the same object: `a.h().g().f()`. I think that using the notation of one for the other isn't great.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I know that in Java, just the buffered objects have such behavior, differently of jQuery, for example. But you all forgot and from now may consider that the library could also be located in the core! By the way, I have Java 7, Guava and Apache Commons available... I was just wondering if there is a well-written-and-tested shortcut, which I don't think that it will be an unreadable, but it maybe would. My objective here is promote another perspective to the coding. We just can't code always the same way, we need improvements.

Comment: @trutheality Your second form is just method chaining, I don't see any direct link to repeated mutation. `a.h().g().f() === f(g(h(a)))` -- all I've changed on the right side is syntax, by putting all function arguments inside parens, instead of the first arg receiving special treatment and being put in front of the function call.

Comment: @Voo thrutheality stated a non-sequitur -- he called the prefix notation "composition" and the infix notation **of the exact same expression** "repeated mutation". The notion of function composition is orthogonal to the notation used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is one line:

```
List<Bean> beans = service.findBeans(); Collections.sort(beans, new BeanComparator()); return beans;
```

But more seriously, Java isn't really the right language for one-liners. Also, just because something is a one-liner doesn't mean that it is any better. For example, I was initially surprised to discover that this:

```
return condition ? a : b;
```

Creates a longer bytecode than

```
if( condition )
    return a;
else
    return b;
```

But that's just how the language and compiler are.

If you insist on your one-liner, [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Ordering`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) can do it:

```
return Ordering.from( new BeanComparator() ).sortedCopy( service.findBeans() );
```

The returned list is modifiable, serializable, and has random access.

Efficiency-wise I think there's a bit of a waste in terms of overhead. And also you're now dependent on a 3rd-party library. You'd be essentially using very powerful tools for a very simple task. It's overkill if this is all you're using it for.

Comment: @thereality And there's such a thing as perl ;) I don't think the first version is especially cluttered. A `sort` version that sorts in-place but returns a reference to the input parameter would imo be badly designed, because most people would expect a sorted copy to be returned from such an API and the input parameter be unchanged. Python - a language that usually keeps quite a good balance between short and readable (much more so than java) - would look pretty much identical for the given problem.

Comment: @trutheality - true... I guess my statement was a little broad.  Just trying to get a point across to those who like to write long, hard to read lines of code ;)

Comment: @trutheality Thanks for the critics and for the Guava option.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the following function will yield the results you want. Just put it in the class of your choice.

```
public static <T> List<T> sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> compare) {
    Collections.sort(list, compare);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use apache CollectionUtils to collate the list with a comparator and an empty list.

```
CollectionUtils.collate(service.findBeans().iterator(),Collections.EMPTY_LIST.iterator(),new beanComparator())
```

CollectionUtils really should add a utility method that returns the sorted list...

Classic rebut to use-more-lines is LOGGING. You logging for readability purposes should not take up more than one line. Logging is static noise when you're trying to find out what code is actually doing, yet logging is fairly critical.

So logging should be compact (in one line) and quiet (should not throw exceptions/be nullsafe) and should be performant (if turned off should not introduce excess processing beyond isDebugOn() check.

Second rebut is fluent interfaces such as JOOQ which are becoming much more prevalent.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you have no duplicates and don't mind hacky code you could use:

```
return new ArrayList<Bean>(new TreeSet<Bean>(service.findBeans()));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach uses the natural ordering to sort, not allowing us to use a custom Comparator.

Answer (score 1):

I think the original question posted is valid.  Because the "Collections.sort(..)" method has the intended side-effect of sorting the passed-in Collection, if you wanted to maintain your original Collection, you'd have to do the following:

```
List<Bean> beans = service.findBeans();
List<Bean> sortedBeans = new ArrayList<Bean>(beans);
Collections.sort(sortedBeans, new BeanComparator());
return sortedBeans;
```

In the case above, it's probably not that big a deal that we sort the Collection returned by a service method.  But, what if the Collection we are sorting was a method parameter, and the caller did not want the Collection passed-in sorted?

I usually prefer to have methods without consequences.

Since "Collections.sort(..)" affects the list, I have to write the following code:

```
public void doSomethingWithBeansInOrder(List<Bean> beans) {
    Collection<Bean> sortedBeans = new ArrayList<Bean>(beans);
    Collections.sort(sortedBeans, ...comparator...;

    for (Bean bean : sortedBeans) {
        .. do something
    }
}
```

I find the definition of "sortedBeans" ugly.

If "(Collections.sort(..)" (or something like it), returned a new Collection and did not affect the passed-in Collection, I could write:

```
public void doSomethingWithBeansInOrder(List<Bean> beans) {
    for (Bean bean : Collections.sort(beans, ...comparator...) {
        .. do something
    }
}
```

The answer for [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Ordering`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) is best, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, Java 8 introduced the [sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) metod on the `List` interface. So, an example of sorting the actual list would be:

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(3, 2, 1);
integerList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
return integerList;
```

Here, I used the pre-defined `naturalOrder()` comparator, which in turn relies on [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), but a custom comparator can also be used. This still requires two statements.

However, if the desired behaviour is to create a new sorted list, and leave the orignial as it was before, I guess a stream would be the easiest way to do it:

```
integerList.stream().sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The same thing as above applies to the comparator here.